# Mercurial: move changes of specific folder to another repo

Tags: version-control, mercurial, directory

I have two mercurial repos, and one folder (project) in each on them (path to this folder differs in each repos). I made many changes with it in one of the repos, and I want to copy this changes from this repo to other one.

Certainly, I can copy all files from modified repo folder to other repo, and commit it. But at this way, I loose all my changes history, and it's bad for me.

What I can do? (if batch, then Win cmd, not bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Convert common folder into repository (`hg convert`)
- add it as subrepo (or guest-repo) into both "super"-repositories
- Have common shared history in subrepo